# Rigi body physics - box inside another box is pushed out of it

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm trying to create a simple physics scene.
I've placed a box inside another box but the box is pushed out of the box.
Even when I flip the normals of the biggest box...
Why is this happening?

[image]

Here is the blend file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cdTgxnJNDxOXfIfCp_iuSubug1SjKPAe

Thx!
Steven

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, because the primitive collision shapes are solid. 
A mesh shape must be used...